# How could I create gaze buttons using React VR?

Tags: webvr, react-360, gaze-buttons

I'm writing an VR application using React VR and would make gaze buttons with a progress bar *(or something)* to show the user how long he must watch to that button. How could I do that?

I'm thinking to use this pseudocode *(may be there are some bug's inside this code)*:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        watchTime: 3,
        progress: 0,
        watching: true
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <VrButton onEnter={ () => this.animateProgress() }
                  onExit={ () => this.stopProgress() }
                  onClick={ ()=> this.click() }></VrButton>
    );
}

animateProgress() {
    this.setState({watching: true});
    while (this.state.watchTime >== this.state.progress && this.state.watching === true) {
        // after a timeout of one second add 1 to `this.state.progress`
    }

    this.click();
}

stopProgress() {
    this.setState({
        progress: 0,
        watching: false
    });
}

click() {
    // Handels the click event
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add some things to your project.

1. Install a [simple raycaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-raycaster) using

   ```
   npm install --save simple-raycaster
   ```

   Inside `vr/client.js` add this code:

   ```js
   import { VRInstance } from "react-vr-web";
   import * as SimpleRaycaster from "simple-raycaster";

   function init(bundle, parent, options) {
     const vr = new VRInstance(bundle, "librarytests", parent, {
       raycasters: [
         SimpleRaycaster // Add SimpleRaycaster to the options 
       ],
       cursorVisibility: "auto", // Add cursorVisibility 
       ...options
     });
     vr.start();
     return vr;
   }

   window.ReactVR = { init };
   ```

   <sup>Source: [npm simple-raycaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-raycaster)</sup>
2. Inside the `index.vr.js` use this code:

   ```babel
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.click = this.click.bind(this); // make sure this.click is in the right context when the timeout is called
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <VrButton onEnter={ () => this.animateProgress() }
                 onExit={ () => this.stopProgress() }
                 onClick={ ()=> this.click() }></VrButton>
     );
   }

   animateProgress() {
     this.timeout = this.setTimeout(this.click, 1000); // or however many milliseconds you want to wait
     // begin animation
   }

   stopProgress() {
     clearTimeout(this.timeout);
     this.timeout = null;
     // end animation
   }

   click() {
     // ...
   }
   ```

   <sup>Source: [andrewimm at GitHub facebook/react-vr](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/168)</sup>